# Excel Pivot Chart with two Categorical Values and Timeline

Tags: excel, graph, pivot-table, categorical-data

I have data in the following format:

´´´

| Name | Date | Method Used | "some other random data"... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | Q1 21 | Method A | .... |
| Bob | Q1 21 | Method B | .... |
| Joe | Q2 21 | Method A | .... |
| Bob | Q2 21 | Method C | ... |
| Joe | Q3 21 | Method C | ... |
| Bob | Q3 21 | Method C | ... |
| Joe | Q4 21 | Method C | ... |
| Bob | Q4 21 | Method B | ... |

´´´

The Output I am looking to create in Excel should look as follows:

[image]